# power series convergence, $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

### $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$

i want to find what is the function that the series converges to,
here is what i tried :

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = (\frac{1}{1-x})$ , when evalutaing $(-x^2) $

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, devide by $x^2 \Rightarrow$
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n-2} = \frac{1}{x^2(1+x^2)}$,  integrate both sides and we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{2n-1} = \int{\frac{1}{x^2(1+x^2)}} = \frac{-1}{x} - \arctan(x) + C$$

but in wolfram it seems that $f(x) = -\arctan(x)$, so what did i do wrong ?

Comment: That divide by $x^2$ step is problematic.  Maybe start your first sum with $i=1$ will fix up your argument.

Comment: it seems that the answer from @josé-carlos-santos is right .. i should not have changed the index ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake took place when you went from$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}$$to$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.$$Since the first sum starts when $i=0$, so should the second one.

Comment: so it should have been $\frac{-1}{x} + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$ ?

Comment: Indeed. But note that the comment by sharding4 is correct too: there was no need to divide by $x^2$.

Comment: can you explain how it should have been done (without dividing by $x^2$ ) ?

Comment: From $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, you can deduce directly that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\arctan(x)$. This is the same thing as saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\arctan(x)$, which is the same thing as saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=-\arctan(x)$.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^n = (\frac{x}{1-x})$, when evaluating $(-x^2)$

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n} = \frac{-x^2}{1+x^2}$, divide by $x^2\implies $

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n-2} = \frac{-1}{(1+x^2)}$, integrate both sides and we get

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{2n-1} = \int{\frac{dx}{1+x^2}} =  - \arctan(x) + C$